# Understanding LDAP/AD Claims Provider

Tags: authentication, people-picker, claims-based-auth, ldap

I'm trying to understand/test this LDAP solution [here](http://ldapcp.codeplex.com/). There is a line of code from the article shown below that I need assistance with.

How do I get my SPTRUST NAME to use in the line shown below?

```
$trust = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "SPTRUST NAME"
```

One last question. I am fairly new in understanding the solution and would like some more clarity on what it does. I have read the article and I do not see the difference between what this solution accomplishes versus what the OOTB people picker from SP 2013 already does. Can someone please assist in helping me understand this solution? Maybe break it down in layman's terms? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of TIPs, run:

```
Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer | Select Name
```

Then you can run:

```
$tip = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "tipName"
```

If you only have one TIP, you can just run:

```
$tip = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer
```

What LDAPCP accomplishes is that it creates a connect to the on-premises directory (e.g. Active Directory) and resolves what users enter into the People Picker. Without custom development, the People Picker will accept any value inputted, regardless if the value is valid or not.

LDAPCP also passes other claims that can be leveraged by the People Picker/users, such as Roles (Active Directory Security Groups).

It has a few other capabilities, as well, such as filtering out disabled objects. I'd strongly recommend this tool simply due to it creating a user friendly People Picker where SAML is implemented.

The only scenario this will not help with is if you do not have direct access to the directory where accounts are originating from, e.g. you've created an ADFS Federation Trust with another company over the Internet -- you're not going to have access to their LDAP in order to use this tool to resolve names in the People Picker.